# Is it possible to query on MultiIndex itself without DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

In case if I have all the needed data contained in `MultiIndex` instance itself, can I query it without attaching it to a data-frame to avoid possible overhead?

For example:

```
In [664]: import pandas as pd

In [665]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

In [666]: df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)

In [667]: df
Out[667]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(A, 1), (A, 2), (A, 3), (A, 4), (A, 5), (B, 1), (B, 2), (B, 3), (B, 4), (B, 5)]
```

In this case I don't have any data in the data-frame itself, all the needed data is stored in the index, so data-frame is redundant. At the same time I'd like to perform queries on the data.

Comment: Can you add sample?

Comment: Your question is unclear, it's possible to have just an index without any data if that's your question

Comment: @EdChum, exactly.

Comment: Well the answer is yes, you can have just an index object, it doesn't need to be attached to a df

Comment: @EdChum, but how to query it?

Comment: @jezrael, see the update of the post plz.

Comment: Did you see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)?

Comment: @EdChum, it talks about querying data-frames and I'd like to query index objects themselves.

Comment: What do you mean by "query"?  What exactly do you want to do with the index?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index method `get_loc_level` this accepts a key value and level:

```
In[143]:
index.get_loc_level(2, level=1)
Out[143]: 

(array([False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool),
 Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object'))
```

so this returns a tuple of the boolean mask, index just the mask and pass this to the index:

```
In[144]:
index.get_loc_level(2, level=1)[0]
Out[144]: array([False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

this returns the level values in a hierarchical array:

```
In[145]:
index[index.get_loc_level(2, level=1)[0]]
Out[145]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
           labels=[[0, 1], [1, 1]])
```

You can then call `.values` to return the index values:

```
In[146]:
index[index.get_loc_level(2, level=1)[0]].values

Out[146]: array([('A', 2), ('B', 2)], dtype=object)
```

This isn't as user friendly as dataframes for querying but if you just want the index to query then this is one method

If you want to query a specific value, it's easier to use `get_level_values` and then use the usual masking operators:

```
In[164]:
index[(index.get_level_values(0) == 'A') & (index.get_level_values(1) == 2)]

Out[164]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
           labels=[[0], [1]])
```

Here is a breakdown to show what is returned:

```
In[165]:
index.get_level_values(0)

Out[165]: Index(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], dtype='object')

In[166]:
index.get_level_values(0) == 'A'

Out[166]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)


In[167]:
index.get_level_values(1) == 2

Out[167]: array([False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```